# rmarkdown caption numbering/reference work with underscores?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

Has anyone else noticed that rmarkdown won't number table captions if the reference uses underscores instead of hyphens? See snippet below. Or build [this website](https://github.com/hdrab127/rmd-site-caption-issue/blob/master/index.Rmd) for a working example.

````
---
title: "Table Captioning"
output:
  bookdown::html_document2:
    number_sections: true
    fig_caption: true
---

# Example

It works in table \@ref(tab:dummy-table) when using hypens.

Table: (\#tab:dummy-table) Some caption.
\```{r dummy-table, echo=FALSE}
knitr::kable(data.frame(a = letters[1:3], 
                        b = 1:3))
\```

But not in table \@ref(tab:dummy_table) when using underscores?

Table: (\#tab:dummy_table) Some caption.
\```{r dummy_table, echo=FALSE}
knitr::kable(data.frame(a = letters[4:6], 
                        b = 4:6))
\```
````

[image: table numbering example]

Not a huge deal, just tripped me up for awhile. Apologies if this behaviour is documented somewhere and I've missed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Section 2.6 in the [RMarkdown book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/r-code.html) suggests that underscores might get you into trouble:

> I strongly recommend that you only use alphanumeric characters (a-z, A-Z and 0-9) and dashes (-) in labels, because they are not special characters and will surely work for all output formats. Other characters, spaces and underscores in particular, may cause trouble in certain packages, such as bookdown.

Now, you're using `bookdown` because of your setup in the YAML:

```
output:
  bookdown::html_document2:
```

You need the `bookdown` option to get the references to work in the first place. The default rmarkdown html output would be `html_document` and that does not work with the automatic referencing. In other words: underscores are off limit for you in R code chunk labels.